# Camtasia, record around the mouse

Tags: mouse, screen-capture, cursor, camtasia

How to record video only around the mouse cursor and when the mouse moves then follow it?

Comment: What version of Camtasia studio are you using?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it myself, but Camtasia's [SmartFocus](http://www.techsmith.com/learn/camtasia/5/editing/smartfocus.asp) feature seems to take care of some of that - following the area of activity.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the current version of Camtasia Studio does not have such a feature. But you can take advantage of Windows Magnifer tool to achieve it.

### Windows Vista and 7:

- Open Magnifer. Under `Options`, tick the `Follow the mouse pointer` checkbox
- Set the zoom level to 200% (or more, if needed) and the screen will pan as you move your mouse. Record the whole screen

### Windows XP:

- This version of Magnifier does not zoom in on the whole screen. Instead you get a window. Check that the `Follow mouse cursor` checkbox is ticked.
- Set the zoom level. Record only the Magnifier window